# hide radio button under checkout payment method

Tags: payment-methods

we are using 5 Payment methods with payment methods codes are "**code1, code2 , code3, code4 and code5**".

for **site** purpose we are using code1 , code2, code3 payment methods.

we have **mobile app** for our site, for that purpose,

we are using code4 , code5 payment methods.

So **code4 and code5** payment methods should not display in site. so i removed those payment methods name. but code4 and code5 payment methods **RADIO BUTTONS** are still displaying in the site.

[image]

in methods.phtml i used this script to remove those radio buttons

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
$_code = $_method->getCode();
if($_code == 'innobyte_payu_lite_cc' or $_code == 'cashondelivery'{continue;} //this line
?>
```

but those Radio buttons are not hiding. **If we disabled the payment method code "code3"** than those radio buttons will hide. but we want the payment method code3 in our site.

**How to hide those radio buttons with payment method code3 enabled in site.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app/design/frontend/your_packge/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

Add bellow code above file after code :`foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
?>`

Add code in file:

```
<?php if(in_array($_code,array('cashondelivery','innobyte_payu_lite_cc'))):?>
    <?php continue;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: still those payment methods radio buttons are displaying : http://pastebin.com/Q2FEkpK9

Comment: Pls add : <?php if(in_array($_code ,array('innobyte_payu_lite_cc','cashondelivery'))):?>
        <?php continue;?>
<?php endif;?>

Comment: i added, please check line number 66 here : http://pastebin.com/Q2FEkpK9

Comment: in your file :   $_code = $_method->getCode(); var name is "$_code"

Comment: then must be add $_code in if condition

like : <?php if(in_array($_code,array('code4','code5'))):?>
        <?php continue;?>
<?php endif;?>

Answer (score 1):

As for I got, you trying to hide some payment methods based on shipping method. For this you don't need to observe things at all. Simply you can do this, just follow me,

Every methods(in one page check out) post the methods which are chosen to the next level. so you can get the shipping method which are chosen, in payment method level. Just print the post things in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

in this add below one,

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

So now you can get the shipping methods which are chosen previous step. And note it, so now, you can add just simple logic (if else) condition in same file for hiding payment,

For example here I want hide check / money order payment method, if shipping method is flat. Here the payment method code is checkmo. you can get payment method code by simply printing that variable like echo  $_code = $_method->getCode(); in same file. so here just add simple if else ,

```
 <?php
    $methods = $this->getMethods();


    $oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;
?>
<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
<?php else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
       echo  $_code = $_method->getCode();


if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
?>
```

Here,

```
if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
```

checks the shipping method and skip the payment method which we don't want to display. That's it. Please comment here if you have any doubt.

**Note:**

```
shipping_method => flatrate_flatrate
 paymet_method   => checkmo
```

please try this update

```
if($_code == 'code1') {
    continue;
}

if($_code == 'code2') {
    continue;
}
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Great answer. i am not worrying about shipping method . all i need is i need to hide radio button of 2 payment methods. asssume payment method codes are : "code1 and code2" . please update the answer.

Comment: please try update...if it is relevant to you.

Comment: now both payment methds radio button are displaying

Comment: do **print_($_code) exit;** and debug with it because the code you defined is may be differ in actual.

Comment: "cashondelivery" is other payment method code

Comment: you can provide code in phtml file???

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZGQ6P4Vk

Comment: check again doing pront_r($_code) and check it is proper in case sensitive. because your code is proper.

Comment: got the real problem. we are using one payment method [code = "code3"], when we enable that payment method , its not working for both. when i disable that payemtn method your solution is working.

Comment: i think template customization problem should be there. please place base template and than try this solution.

Comment: i will try that....

Comment: i hope this will help you buddy...if you get solution than hope for rate...answer.

Comment: i tried with base template, still not working. please check updated question

Comment: it is somehow verse situation than ago question but i still find solution if possible gives you update.

Comment: ya, please check it. this is really needed for me

Answer (score 1):

simply use this **or** condition work for you.

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
            $_code = $_method->getCode();
            if($_code == 'cashondelivery' or $_code == 'YOUR_CODE2'){continue;}
            ?>
```

Comment: now both payment methods radio button are displaying.

Comment: you don't want to show?

Comment: i dont want to show both radio buttons

Comment: update the answer

Comment: got the real problem. we are using one payment method [code = "code3"], when we enable that payment method , its not working for both. when i disable that payemtn method your solution is working.

Comment: you want to hide if payment method is active too?

Comment: i willl update the question in few minutes

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: did you try last updated answer..

Comment: yes, i tried that one also.....

Comment: i check your website there is only radio is showing for i add the if statement try it or else i have to see the admin for that

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
    $_code = $_method->getCode();
    if($_code!="code1" || $_code!="code2"){//display the methods.
        here unwanted methods are not show.
}
```

try this way.
Assign your requested methods to an array.

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
$_code = $_method->getCode();
 $requestedmethod = array("method1","method2");//You have you methods codes
 if(in_array($_code,$requestedmethod)){
  //This will omit the unwanted method and Show only the methods you want
 }
```

UPDATE : you can use this code .Just Try this.i Check your page and found three methods you want to show.so i added those 3 methods to array and check while iterating the foreach.

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
    $_code = $_method->getCode();
    $requested_paymont_methods = array("mpcashondelivery","hdfc_standard","payucheckout_shared");
 <?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
if(in_array($_code,$requested_paymont_methods)){?>
  //This will omit the unwanted method and Show only the methods you want
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
 <?php } ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Comment: now both payment methds radio button are displaying

Comment: use the in_array method

Comment: got the real problem. we are using one payment method [code = "code3"], when we enable that payment method , its not working for both. when i disable that payemtn method your solution is working.

Comment: So you find a solution right :).

Comment: no this is the problem. i can not displae that payment method

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: you have following payment methods right?.
mpcashondelivery,
hdfc_standard,
payucheckout_shared,
cashondelivery,
innobyte_payu_lite_cc

Comment: sorry for delay... thanks a lot for your support......